# DoEvents with Webbrowser hanging application

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I've inherited some code which automates a Webbrowser control and is having some trouble. While processing, the first time running a task, it can process with no issue. However, the second time it will hang up about halfway through processing. In debugging, it looks like it is always hung on a call to Application.DoEvents().

A small sample of code and where it gets stuck:

```
RS: Try
        Do Until ie2.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents() ' WILL LOOK STUCK HERE
            If SecondsCounted >= 20 Then Exit Do
            UpdateBrowserLabel(ie2.Name, DiagnosticLabelString & " - NOT COMPLETE!")
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        fmain.lblDiagnostic.Text = "exception: ReadyState loop"
        TickTick("0.1")
        GoTo RS
    End Try
```

There are two timers (System.Windows.Forms.Timer) running, one of which runs at interval 1000 and contains a DoEvents call and increments the SecondsCounted variable. The second timer has an interval of 5, contains a call to DoEvents() and calls LockSetForegroundWindow from user32.

While running, the program starts to really slow down. It looks like any time the Webbrowser has done something with javascript, then "pausing" will show the program on a call to "DoEvents", which takes longer and longer to finish.

How can I stop my application from bogging down over time and eventually freezing? Is there something better than DoEvents in order to keep the program responsive? I tried just removing all of the calls to DoEvents and the program actually stopped working.

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It will stop on DoEvents when you randomly break the program 99.9% of the time.  You need to scrap this code and rewrite it, it is a buggy mess that you cannot trust.

Comment: Thanks - That's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will repeat frantically until the browser has completed or 20 seconds has passed. Perhaps you do not need the loop - checking every second to see whether the browser has completed might be enough.

It seems to get stuck on DoEvents because that's the command that allows the process to respond to other things (i.e. your request to pause the app)

The world has gone much more Async since VB6, and so the current way to keep the UI responsive is to use events and callbacks. You might be able to do this with the web browser - I'm pretty sure that it will raise and event when it has completed or experienced an error.

Comment: Thanks - I like the idea of not polling in the loop infinitely a lot. I agree that everything is too synchronous right now, but that is a bit out of my control.